# What is the best way to hold a status (TO_DO, IN_PROGRESS, DONE) for Project, Phase of project and template of phase

Tags: java

I need to do a status for project, phase and templates.

[Example in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ2HI.png)

[image]

I tried to have a Map with (PhaseID,TemplateID,Status).
Can you give me a better idea , what can i have this : Project id, Phase id, TemplateId and Status(TO_DO,Done)?

The Project class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private java.lang.String name;

    @NotNull
    private Integer size;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<ProjectPhase> phases = new ArrayList<>();

    public Project(){}

    public Project(java.lang.String name, Integer size, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public List<ProjectPhase> getPhases() {
        return phases;
    }

    public void setPhases(List<ProjectPhase> phases) {
        this.phases = phases;
    }
}
```

The Phase class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phases")
public class ProjectPhase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<ProjectPhaseTemplate> projectPhaseTemplates;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();


    public ProjectPhase() {
    }

    public ProjectPhase(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public ProjectPhase(String name, List<ProjectPhaseTemplate> projectPhaseTemplates) {
        this.name = name;
        this.projectPhaseTemplates = projectPhaseTemplates;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<ProjectPhaseTemplate> getProjectPhaseTemplates() {
        return projectPhaseTemplates;
    }

    public void setProjectPhaseTemplates(List<ProjectPhaseTemplate> projectPhaseTemplates) {
        this.projectPhaseTemplates = projectPhaseTemplates;
    }

    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

}
```

The Template class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
public class ProjectPhaseTemplate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public ProjectPhaseTemplate() {
    }

    public ProjectPhaseTemplate(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I can't have a field of "Status" for each of them,  because Phase can be in more project and Templates can be in more Phases. If i set a "Status" to a template , it will be the same status for all phases that have that template.

I want to be like this.
If all templates it s marked like "DONE" , the Phase change the Status to "Done.
If all phases that belongs to Project  it's marked "Done, the Project change the Status to "Done"
So i need just for template a Status.

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you are asking for, but isn't it just a new field "private StatusEnum status;" in your classes? Please edit your question to elaborate your problem

Comment: @Progman i edited .

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relationship (maybe with a diagram) on how the projects, phases and templates are related to each other. It looks like you have some 1-to-N or N-to-M relationships here, but is not clear how.

Comment: @Progman I have N-to-M for Project-Phase and N-to-M for Phase-Templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class `StatusInformation` which holds all the information for a given Project-Phase-Template path and the status it has. It will look something like this:

```
public class StatusInformation {
    private Project project;
    private Phase phase;
    private Template template;
    private StatusEnum status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

This way you can express the following statement:

> "The template X in the phase Y which is used in project Z is in status TODO"

And for a slightly different combination you can have different status values:

> "The template X in the phase y which is used in project **A** is in status DONE"